# Qualified-id call to base function via pointer

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

If I have a virtual function `foo()` first defined in a base class `B` and then overridden in a derived class `D`, how can I store the address of `B::foo` in a pointer-to-member-function in a way such that when calling it, the call would behave as a qualified-id call (like `pd->B::foo()`)?

Example:

```
struct B {
    virtual int foo() { return 1; }
};

struct D: public B {
    virtual int foo() { return 2; }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    D* pd = new D();
    int (B::*pf)() = &B::foo;
    int r = (pd->*pf)();
    return 0; 
}
```

This would call `D::foo()`. Can I initialize `pf` in a way such that the `(pd->*pf)()` would call `B::foo()` even if `pd`'s dynamic type is a class that overrides `foo()`?

(Before anyone asks, I don't really want to do this, I'm just curious if it's possible.)

Comment: Cheap hack: `int (*fp)(B &) = [](B & b) { return b.B::foo(); };`

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can.
I don't have my standard with me, but using the vararg hack to print the values of the pointer to member functions http://ideone.com/bRk7mG:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>
using namespace std;

struct Test
{
    void foo() {};
    virtual void bar() {}; 
    virtual void bar2() {};
    virtual void bar3() {};
};

void print_hack(int dummy, ...)
{
    va_list argp;
    va_start(argp, dummy);
    long val = va_arg(argp, long);
    cout << val << endl;
    va_end(argp);
}

int main() {
    print_hack (0, &Test::foo);
    print_hack (0, &Test::bar);
    print_hack (0, &Test::bar2);
    print_hack (0, &Test::bar3);
    return 0;
}
```

It seems like the value stored in the pointer (at least for GCC) is the index in the objects virtual table.
For non-virtual functions it seems like a regular function pointer.

Basically you are forced to do dynamic dispatch when using a pointer-to-member-function that holds a virtual function, at least as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with StoryTeller, I don't think it is possible in any standard-compliant way. If what you really want to achieve is to be able to call either the base class implementation or derived class implementation using the same function pointer, the best I can recommend is this:

```
struct B {
    virtual int foo() { return fooB(); }
    int fooB() { return 1; }
};

struct D: public B {
    virtual int foo() { return 2; }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    D* pd = new D();
    int (B::*pf)() = &B::fooB;
    int r = (pd->*pf)();
    return 0; 
}
```

Since the function pointer type is the same whether a function is virtual or not, then creating a non-virtual function in the base class allows you to take its address directly.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with snakedoctor, you should do :

```
int r = pd->B::foo()
```

It is just a call to the mother's method.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just do:

```
pd->B::foo()
```

Comment: This really should be a comment, but that aside, the OP answered it already.